# SQL Insert multiple rows to 1:n table association

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables (simplified for the question) like the following:

```
Candidate
   - ID (primary key auto-numbered)
   - ProcessedOn
   - CandidateState

CandidateData
   - CandidateID
   - FieldKey
   - FieldValue

CandidateTransform
   - ID (primary key auto-numbered)
   - FieldKey 
   - FieldValue
```

CandidateTransform contains data that is used to populate CandidateData (i.e., FieldKey -> FieldKey and FieldValue -> FieldValue).  FieldValue in CandeidateTransform contains a string of SQL that selects the FieldValue from another database/table (personnel information) like so:

```
(SELECT firstName FROM Personnel WHERE id = @CandidateID)
```

I was able to do this previously as we would only process one candidate at a time and we would create a stored procedure with the INSERT statement like this:

```
DECLARE @NewCandidate TABLE (id bigint);

INSERT CloudRecruiting.Candidate (CandidateState, ActHdrKey, ActionProcessedOn, JobPostingID, Deleted)
OUTPUT INSERTED.CandidateKey INTO @NewCandidate
VALUES (0, 0, GETDATE(), @PlacementID, 0);

DECLARE @ID bigint;
SET @ID = (SELECT id FROM @NewCandidate);

DECLARE @CandidateID bigint;
SET @CandidateID = (SELECT candidate FROM Personnel WHERE id = @PlacementID);

INSERT INTO .CandidateData (CandidateKey, FieldKey, FieldValue) 
    VALUES (@ID, 1128, (SELECT ISNULL(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateOfBirth, 120), 10), '') FROM Personnel WHERE id = @CandidateID))
    , (@ID, 1159, (SELECT email FROM Personnel WHERE id = @CandidateID))
    , (@ID, 1284, (SELECT ssn FROM Personnel WHERE id = @CandidateID))
    , (@ID, 1303, CAST((SELECT payRate FROM Personnel WHERE id = @PlacementID) as nvarchar(MAX)))
    , (@ID, 1169, (SELECT firstName FROM Personnel WHERE id = @CandidateID))
    , (@ID, 1229, (SELECT middleName FROM Personnel WHERE id = @CandidateID))
    , (@ID, 1219, (SELECT lastName FROM Personnel WHERE id = @CandidateID))
    (etc.)
```

Now we want to make the process more robust by storing the SELECT statements in a table (CandidateTransform) that the customer can modify and be able to process multiple candidates in one batch via a stored procedure like this (we currently have SQL that will capture the CandidateIDs that we need to process and stores them in a tempTable) :

```
for each (candidateID in tempTable)
   create entry in Candidate
   capture new id number from Candidate

   for each (sql in CandidateTransform)
      execute sql script
      store value in CandidateData with the new id, FieldKey and FieldValue
   end
end
```

I have not used the while feature of SQL and not sure if this is the best approach or if there is some other SQL that I can use to do what I need.  Any solution needs to support SQL 2008 or later.

Comment: Basically- what you can do with one row, you can do with multiple rows at the same time. So instead of only working on one row, you should be able to select from/join into tempTable and then do the same `output inserted ....` that you're already doing on all of the rows in one go

Comment: The bigger issue is how do I store the SLEECT statements currently in the INSERT statement in a table and read all of the rows to get the data I need.

Comment: You'll likely need to dynamically build your query up based on those the statements/data the customer can change. So if you store those data, then append that to the rest of your query and execute it as a string.